# Searching for a sum in an array

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I have a method which counts how many sums of 3 elements,which are equal to 0, does the array contains. I need help finding the way **to stop counting the same triplets** in the loop. For instance, 1 + 3 - 4 = 0, but also 3 - 4 +1 = 0.Here is the method:

```
private static int counter(int A[])
    {   
         int sum;
         int e = A.length;
         int count = 0;
         for (int i=0; i<e; i++)
         {
             for (int j=i+1; j<e; j++)
             {
                 sum=A[i]+A[j];
                 if(binarySearch(A,sum))
                 {
                      count++;
                 }
             }  
         }
         return count;
```

edit: I have to use the Binary Search (the array is sorted).
Here is the binarySearch code:

```
   private static boolean binarySearch(int A[],int y)
    {   
        y=-y;
        int max = A.length-1;
        int min = 0;
        int mid;
        while (max>=min)
        {      
            mid = (max+min)/2;
            if (y==A[mid])
            {
                return true;
            }   
            if (y<A[mid]) 
            {
                max=mid-1;
            }
            else
            {
                min=mid+1;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: actually your binarySearch is not giving correct output.

Comment: I made a few edits again...(binarySearch int --->bolean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid counting different triplets by making one assumption that we need to look for the triplets (x,y,z) with `x < y < z` and `A[x] + A[y] + A[z] == 0`.

So what you need to do is to modify the binarySearch function to return the number of index that greater than y and has A[z] == -(A[x] + A[y])

```
private static int binarySearch(int A[],int y, int index)
    {   
        y=-y;
        int max = A.length-1;
        int min = index + 1;
        int mid;
        int start = A.length;
        int end = 0;
        while (max>=min)
        {      
            mid = (max+min)/2;
            if (y==A[mid])
            {
                start = Math.min(start, mid);
                max = mid - 1;
            } else  
            if (y<A[mid]) 
            {
                max=mid-1;
            }
            else
            {
                min=mid+1;
            }
        }
        int max = A.length - 1;
        int min = index + 1;
        while (max>=min)
        {      
            mid = (max+min)/2;
            if (y==A[mid])
            {
                end = Math.max(end, mid);
                min= mid + 1;
            } else if (y<A[mid]) 
            {
                max=mid-1;
            }
            else
            {
                min=mid+1;
            }
        }
        if(start <= end) 
           return end - start + 1;
        return 0;
}
```

So the new function `binarySearch` will return the total number of index that greater than `index` and has value equals to `y`.

So the rest of the job is to count the answer

```
private static int counter(int A[])
{   
     int sum;
     int e = A.length;
     int count = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<e; i++)
     {
         for (int j=i+1; j<e; j++)
         {
             sum=A[i]+A[j];
             count += binarySearch(A,sum, j);

         }  
     }
     return count;
}
```

Notice how I used two binary search to find the starting and the ending index of all values greater than `y`!

Comment: Thank you for helping me,I didnt thought that thing with the 2 binary searches.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int counter(int A[]) {
    int e = A.length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; (j < e - 1) && (i != j); j++) {
            for (int k = 2; (k < e - 2) && (j != k); k++) {
                if (A[i] + A[j] + A[k] == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the binary search for faster execution time.

Comment: But you didn't said that your array is sorted?? @DiVeRsi0n

Comment: Sry,I forgot it...The array is sorted.Thats why I can use Binary Search.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int counter(int ints[]) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) {
        // cannot sum with itself.
        continue;
      }
      for (int k = 0; k < ints.length; k++) {
        if (k == j) {
          // cannot sum with itself.
          continue;
        }

        if ((ints[i] + ints[j] + ints[k]) == 0) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but as I said above I have to use the Binary Search to find the triplets.

Answer (score 0):

**To solve problem with binary search**
Your code was almost correct. all you needed to do was just to replace

```
if (sum == binarySearch(A,sum)) {
```

with this

```
if (binarySearch(A,sum)) {
```

*I am assuming that your `binarySearch(A, sum)` method will return **`true`** if it will found `sum` in `A` array else **`false`***

```
private static int counter(int A[]) {   
    int sum;
    int e = A.length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<e; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<e; j++) {
            sum=A[i]+A[j];
            if (binarySearch(A,sum)) {
                count++;
            }  
        }  
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: My binarySearch method returns an int which is equals to the -sum of the other 2 ints.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing then?

Comment: Could you use `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution assuming the array is sorted and there are no repeated elements, I used the binary search function you provided. Could the input array contain repeated elements? Could you provide some test cases?

In order to not counting the same triplets in the loop, we should have a way of inspecting repeated elements, the main idea that I used here is to have a list of int[] arrays saving the sorted integers of `{A[i],A[j],-sum}`.Then in each iteration I compare new A[i] and A[j] to the records in the list, thus eliminating repeated ones.

```
    private static int counter(int A[]){   
     int sum;
     int e = A.length;
     int count = 0;
     List<int[]> elements = new ArrayList<>();
     boolean mark = false;
     for (int i=0; i<e; i++)
     {
         for (int j=i+1; j<e; j++)
         {
             sum=A[i]+A[j];

             if (-sum == binarySearch(A,sum)){
                 int[] sort = {A[i],A[j],-sum};
                 if(-sum == A[i] || -sum == A[j]){
                     continue;
                 }else{
                     Arrays.sort(sort);
                     //System.out.println("sort" + sort[0] + " " + sort[1]+ " " + sort[2]);
                     for (int[] element : elements) {
                         if((element[0] == sort[0] && element[1] == sort[1]) && element[2] == sort[2])
                             mark = true;
                     }
                     if(mark){
                         mark = false;
                         continue;
                     }else{
                         count++;
                         elements.add(sort);
                         //System.out.println("Else sort" + sort[0] + " " + sort[1]);
                     }
                 }
             }  
         }  
     }
     return count;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working but it takes much more time to be executed...I want to reduce it...(yes the array is sorted and there are not repeated elements).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a assisted Array,stored the flag that indicate if the element is used;
Here is the code:

```
private static int counter(int A[])
{   
     int sum;
     int e = A.length;
     int count = 0;
     // assisted flag array
     List<Boolean> flagList = new ArrayList<Boolean>(e);
     for (int k = 0; k < e; k++) {
        flagList.add(k, false);// initialization
     }
     for (int i=0; i<e; i++)
     {
         for (int j=i+1; j<e; j++)
         {
             sum=A[i]+A[j];
             // if element used, no count
             if(binarySearch(A,sum)&& !flagList.get(i)&& !flagList.get(j))
             {
                  count++;
                  flagList.set(i, true);
                  flagList.set(j, true);
             }
         }  
     }
     return count;
```